# Cant Adding to detail page user's posts İn django

Tags: python, django

Hey ı am trying to add the user's post to the detail page with DetailView but ı cant add this is the code ı wrote

**profile.py**

```
        from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
        from django.views.generic import DetailView
        from account.models import CustomUserModel
        from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
        
    class ProfilDetailView(DetailView):
    ​
        template_name = 'pages/profil.html'
        context_object_name='profil'
def get(self,request):
        profil = get_object_or_404(
            CustomUserModel,username=self.kwargs.get('username')
            )
        yazi = get_object_or_404(YazilarModel,yazar=profil.username)
        return render(request,'pages/profil.html',context={
            'profil':profil,
            'yazilar':yazi.all()
            })
```

**urls.py**

```
    path('kullanıcı/<str:username>',ProfilDetailView.as_view(),name='profil'),
```

**profil.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% load static %}


{% block title %} {{profil.username}} {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="card mb-3">
    <div class="row g-0">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            {% if profil.avatar %}
            <img src="{{profil.avatar.url}}" class="rounded" class="pt-4" width="200px" height="200px "
                style="border: radius 15%; margin-right:20px; " alt="">
            {% else %}
            <img src="{% static 'img/no-avatar.jpg'%}" class="rounded" class="pt-4" width="200px" height="200px "
                style="border: radius 15%; margin-right:20px; " alt="">
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card-body">
                {% if profil.get_full_name == '' %}
                <h5 class="card-title"> Adı : Girilmemiş</h5>
                <h5 class="card-title"> Soyadı : Girilmemiş</h5>
                {% else %}
                <h5 class="card-title"> Adı : {{profil.first_name}}</h5>
                <h5 class="card-title mb-5"> Soyadı : {{profil.last_name}}</h5>
                {% endif %}
                <h5>Hakkında :</h5>
                <hr>
                <p>Bla Bla Bla</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>

{%endblock%}
```

**yazilar.py in models**

```
from distutils.command.upload import upload
from enum import unique
from autoslug import AutoSlugField
from django.db import models
from forum.models import KategoriModel
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from forum.abstract_models import DateAbstractModel
from django_resized import ResizedImageField
class YazilarModel(DateAbstractModel):
    resim = ResizedImageField(verbose_name='image',size=[320,214.34],upload_to='yazi_resimler')
    baslik = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    icerik = RichTextField()
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='baslik',unique=True)
    kategoriler = models.ManyToManyField(KategoriModel,related_name='yazi')
    yazar = models.ForeignKey('account.CustomUserModel',related_name='yazilar',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Yazi'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Yazilar'
        db_table = 'Yazi'
        
        
        
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.baslik
```

when ı start the server  ı get this error
profildetailview.get_object() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
can you help me thank you?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do the "get function". Instead you need to define the model in your view. Do it like like this:

```
from .models import YazilarModel

class ProfilDetailView(DetailView):
        template_name = 'pages/profil.html'
        model = YazilarModel
        context_object_name='profil'
```

Comment: AttributeError at /account/kullanici/root
Generic detail view ProfilDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf. ı got this error now ı didn't get the problem .

Comment: You cannot have a string in the url as you have right now, you need a primary key or a slug.